# Break the string using Regex C#

Tags: .net, regex, string, c#-4.0, break

```
var str =  "AB: Pillow D-001-134552";
```

I want to break the above string to `[D-001-134552]` using Regex.(starting position D occupies only one char, next 001 is 3 characters but last path can take single number or 7digits also).

Comment: What did you try? Please show some effort on your part.

Comment: Why not split with a space and then with hyphens? [`var result = str.Split().LastOrDefault().Split('-');`](https://ideone.com/MBkAgx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just want the id-string, no need to work with capture groups in this case.
So one line should suffice.

The solution below assumes that the id has a certain format:
1 character, dash, 3 digits, dash, 6 to 7 digits.

```cs
string str = "AB: Pillow D-001-134552";

var id = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str, @"\w-\d{3}-\d{6,7}").Value;
```